# asp.net no response from post request after injecting HostingEnvironment

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, code-injection

I only have basic knowledge about ASP.net. I have been writing a simple MVP controller, that processes a JSON post request. It worked fine until I tried injecting Hosting environment. Since then the server always responds with code 500, but there are no errors on the server itself. When setting breakpoints in the controller it seems like the post code is never reached, not even the constructor is called after the injection. I have no idea where to look for the reason for this. I hope someone can help me here. Here is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Annotations;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.AcroForms;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using st214.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace st214.API
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FormularController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
    private readonly HostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    private readonly string tempLocation;

    private Dictionary<string, string> locationsMock = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public FormularController(ApplicationDbContext context, HostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        db = context;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

        tempLocation = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\app\formularwesen\tempForms\";

        locationsMock.Add(@"ct", @"CT_form.pdf");
        locationsMock.Add(@"uewa", @"UeWA_form.pdf");
        locationsMock.Add(@"uelab", @"UeWA_form.pdf");
        locationsMock.Add(@"uelabalt", @"UeWA_form.pdf");
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public FileStreamResult Post([FromBody] FormData formData)
    {
        var source = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\app\formularwesen\PDFForms\" + locationsMock[formData.name];
        var file = FillForm(source, tempLocation, formData.data, formData.print);

        FileStream pdfStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = formData.name + ".pdf"
        };
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] FormData formData)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    private string FillForm(string source, string destinationFolder, Dictionary<string, FormField> fields, bool print)
    {
        // Open document
        PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(source, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

        // set fields to be editable
        if (document.AcroForm.Elements.ContainsKey("/NeedAppearances") == false)
            document.AcroForm.Elements.Add("/NeedAppearances", new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfBoolean(true));
        else
            document.AcroForm.Elements["/NeedAppearances"] = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfBoolean(true);

        // fill out fields
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FormField> field in fields)
        {
            // get the field
            if (field.Value.Type == "text")
            {
                PdfTextField currentField = (PdfTextField)(document.AcroForm.Fields[field.Key]);
                // create the value
                PdfString valueString = new PdfString(field.Value.Value);
                // fill the value
                try
                {
                    currentField.Value = valueString;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException e)
                {
                    // Field not found
                }
            }

            if (field.Value.Type == "radio")
            {
                PdfCheckBoxField currentField = (PdfCheckBoxField)(document.AcroForm.Fields[field.Value.Value]);

                try
                {
                    if (currentField.HasKids)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in currentField.Fields.Elements.Items)
                        {
                            //assumes you want to "check" the checkbox.  Use "/Off" if you want to uncheck.
                            //"/Yes" is defined in your pdf document as the checked value.  May vary depending on original pdf creator.
                            ((PdfDictionary)(((PdfReference)(item)).Value)).Elements.SetName(PdfAcroField.Keys.V, "/Yes");
                            ((PdfDictionary)(((PdfReference)(item)).Value)).Elements.SetName(PdfAnnotation.Keys.AS, "/Yes");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentField.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException e)
                {
                    // field not found
                }
            }
        }


        // create unique file name (UUID)
        string tmpName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";

        string file = destinationFolder + tmpName;

        // if file should be printed immediately, add print function to
        // pdf document
        if(print)
            AddPrintFunction(document);

        // save the document
        document.Save(file);

        return file;
    }
    public static void AddPrintFunction(PdfDocument document)
    {
        PdfDictionary dict = new PdfDictionary(document);

        // According to the PDF Reference the dictionary requires two elements.
        // A key /S that specifies the action name, and a key /JS that set the JavaScript to run.
        dict.Elements["/S"] = new PdfName("/JavaScript");
        dict.Elements["/JS"] = new PdfName("/this.print(true);");

        document.Internals.AddObject(dict);
        document.Internals.Catalog.Elements["/OpenAction"] = PdfInternals.GetReference(dict);
    }

    private string getTemplateFile(string templateName)
    {
        FormLocation template = db.FormLocations.Where(f => f.name == templateName).First();
        return template.file;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the system events viewer ?

Comment: how are you injecting dependencies?

Comment: simply adding it to the constructor

Comment: You're not meant to have instantiated instances of HostingEnvironment. All it's (useful) members are static, and the constructor is meant to be called ["only once by the application's ApplicationManager object"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.hostingenvironment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (i.e. not called by you). I imagine that your injector is choking trying to instantiate a new instance of HostingEnvironment. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Ah, ok, that might be it. The weird thing is that we deployed a similar version of this controller yesterday from a different branch and it worked fine. But I'll try without instantiating it.

Comment: ok, apparently its members are not static... when I add it to the constructor I can access the WebRootPath etc., but when using it as a static class they are not there...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it out myself. You need to inject `IHostingEnvironment`, not `HostingEnvironment` for it to work. I am not experienced enough to explain what each of those is, maybe someone can clarify it in the comments, just wanted to answer the question as I found the problem.